# Safest Means of Deleting Old Messages in Dovecot

Tags: dovecot, imap

So I'm trying to setup automated deletion of messages in Dovecot using a cronjob to run a daily `doveadm expunge` and weekly `doveadm purge` to clear out old messages with some given criteria (mostly stuff in trash and junk folders, everything else I archive instead).

The problem is with an expunge command like the following:

```
doveadm expunge -A SEEN BEFORE 7d MAILBOX Trash
```

This seems like a good balance, however if a user opens an unread message right on the edge of the 7 day cut-off, it could get deleted before they can do something with it, such as move it to another mailbox.

It's an edge case I know, but I was hoping to do some kind of multi-stage delete by having all new messages flagged as Recent, such that I could do something like:

```
doveadm expunge -A OLD SEEN BEFORE 7d MAILBOX Trash
doveadm flags -A remove '\Recent' SEEN BEFORE 7d MAILBOX Trash
```

By expunging *before* removing the `\Recent` flag this means that any messages that are seen right on the cut-off date will get an extra day or so before they're actually deleted. Problem is I can't find anything that actually describes how to set `\Recent` on all new messages (and `sieve` can't seem to do this).

What I'm wondering is; is there a way for me to control when `\Recent` is set so that I can actually make the above work, and if not, is there another means of achieving the same goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've arrived at is by adding a custom flag to messages that are about to be deleted. I do this in my nightly script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Save unread messages from their impending doom
doveadm flags remove -A 'Doomed' UNSEEN KEYWORD 'Doomed'
# Soft-delete messages that were doomed by the previous pass
doveadm flags add -A '\Deleted' KEYWORD 'Doomed' SEEN

# Doom messages older than a week. In reality this will probably be
# several commands tailored to different users and/or mailboxes
doveadm flags add -A 'Doomed' SEEN SAVEDBEFORE 7d

# Purge all messages that were expunged by the previous pass
doveadm purge -A
# Expunge all messages that were deleted in this pass
doveadm expunge -A DELETED MAILBOX '*'
```

This essentially sets up a multi-stage deletion consisting of two-steps for most mailboxes, with three steps for `mdbox` based mailboxes:

- First, each message that has been seen by the user is marked as `Doomed`. (1)
- On the next pass, all messages that are still `Doomed` have the `\Deleted` flag added. (2)
- Finally on the third pass the message is actually purged from an `mdbox`'s storage. (3)

If the script is run once every 24 hours, then this gives a minimum 24 hour delay between a message being read (being marked `Doomed`), and it actually being deleted. In an `mdbox` there is then a further 24 hours before the message is gone completely.

1. The marking of messages as `Doomed` would most likely involve more separate commands for per-user and per-mailbox behaviours, and should be preceded by any kind of archival actions. For example, in my case I move old messages from protected mailboxes to an Archive mailbox which is exempted from deletion (and moved to compressed storage with alt-move).
2. If you don't use `mdbox` (though IMO everyone should) then the step adding the `\Deleted` flag could be replaced with an `expunge`, in which case the last two commands can be dropped.
3. In setups without `mdbox` based accounts the `purge` command is a no-op.